# Integral over a ball

Tags: integration

Let $a=(1,2)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $B(a,3)$ denote a ball in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ centered at $a$ and of radius equal to $3$.
Evaluate the following integral:
$$\int_{B(a,3)}y^{3}-3x^{2}y \ dx dy$$

Should I use polar coordinates? Or is there any tricky solution to this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that $\Delta(y^3-3x^2y)=0$, so that $y^3-3x^2y$ is [harmonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function). By the [mean value property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property), we get that the mean value over the ball is the value at the center. Since the area of the ball is $9\pi$ and the value at the center is $2$, we get
$$
\int_{B(a,3)}\left(y^3-3x^2y\right)\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y=18\pi
$$

Comment: On the ball, as always. +1

Comment: Super slick, +1

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very tricky :)

Comment: Not so tricky when you recognize $y^3-3x^2y=-\mathrm{Im}\left((x+iy)^3\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the brute force approach. 
Let $f(x,y) = y^3-3x^2y$. 
Shift so the center of the ball is at the origin and go to polar coordinates.
The integral is then
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3 f(r\cos\theta+1,r\sin\theta+2)
r dr d\theta.$$ 
The integral is straightforward but tedious, with value $18\pi$ as found by @robjohn in his much slicker answer.